# Facebook SDK 4 in Android Studio ExceptionInitializeError Login v2.3

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

First and foremost could someone provide me a sample that just connects and switch to another fragment when logged in that would be great so I'll have working code I can look at to understand.
I'm just trying to put a Login button on a test page when the user is connected with facebook then the fragment should change. I tried what's there : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3 but I can't get it working and don't really understand what's going on.. So I'm lost. I'm having a `ExceptionInitializeError` with the following code. But I doubt it is correct.

My login fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_frag, container, false);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setFragment(this);

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    monFragmentManager = new MonFragmentManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    monFragmentManager.showFragment(0, false);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            monFragmentManager.showFragment(1,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            monFragmentManager.showFragment(0,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            monFragmentManager.showFragment(0,false);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Here's a sample that adds the login button: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/Scrumptious

Why do you register a callback to the same button twice?

Comment: Please provide the full error/stack trace (you can link to a paste on pastebin.com), and elaborate which line of your example code maps to which line of your stack trace.

Comment: I fixed the error by following a tutorial from slide nerd. Thanks anyway. Sorry for answering late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace a fragment, you need to obtain an instance of a [`FragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html). On this instance, you call [`.beginTransaction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()) to obtain a [`FragmentTransaction`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) instance. On this transaction instance, you can call [`.replace()`](http://bit.ly/1OQkuEN). This takes two arguments: The ID of the container inside which you want to replace fragments, and the instance of the fragment that you want to display after the replace. Finally, you need to call [`.commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit()) on the transaction instance for the changes to take effect.

You could do all this inside the `onSuccess()` method that is defined in the anonymous inner `FacebookCallback<LoginResult>` class within your `MainActivity`:

```
// ...
// obtain someFragmentManager instance
// obtain containerViewId instance
// ...

@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
  someFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(containerViewId, otherFragment)
    .commit();
}
```

You can see an example of replacing fragments on [this page of the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace).

Comment: I had a fragment manager in my code, line 4 is an object I created in which the constructor takes a FragmentManager object in argument. Sorry for answering this late I actually found a nice tutorial from slidenerd on youtube and I forgot about this thread.

Comment: From your code it is not apparent what exactly `MonFragmentManager` is, which is why I my answer explains that you need to get an instance of a `FragmentManager`-compatible class.